# How can I increase the number of faces of a triangular mesh using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mesh

I would like to increase the number of faces of a triangular mesh computed using isosurface in Matlab. `reducevolume` works well to reduce the number of faces, but would I would like to do is the opposite. Any suggestions on how to implement this easily using Matlab?

Thank you,
Marta

Comment: Check this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16215-triangular-mesh-refinement

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with mesh manipulation, but I think using the reducepatch function could work. It works by either reducing the number of faces to the input fraction 'r' if it is less than 1, or it makes 'r' number of faces if greater than 1.

[MATLAB's Documentation of reducepatch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reducepatch.html)

I hope this helps.  Also, I've found that saving a MATLAB function's source code as a different file name and messing around with it until it does what you want helps too. (This can be done most simply by purposefully retrieving an error using the function and clicking the line number next to the desired function).